# Am getting an "Error: Semicolons aren't allowed in the indented syntax" when using svelte with sass

Tags: sass, svelte

Tried to read the documentation and correct some issues relating to sass. Added "lang=scss" to the component, but not sure how to correct this issue. Any guidance will be helpful.

```
rollup v2.19.0
bundles src/main.js → public\build\bundle.js...
[!] (plugin svelte) Error: semicolons aren't allowed in the indented syntax.  ╷
2 │ $primary: hsl(180, 29%, 50%);
  │                             ^
  ╵
  stdin 2:29  root stylesheet
```

When changing the code to reflect lang="sass", I get the same:

```
bundles src/main.js → public\build\bundle.js...
[!] (plugin svelte) Error: semicolons aren't allowed in the indented syntax.
  ╷
2 │ $primary: hsl(180, 29%, 50%);
  │                             ^
  ╵
  stdin 2:29  root stylesheet
src\App.svelte
Error: semicolons aren't allowed in the indented syntax.
  ╷
2 │ $primary: hsl(180, 29%, 50%);
  │                             ^
  ╵
  stdin 2:29  root stylesheet
```

Comment: scss and sass use a slighly different syntax (one of them is the use of semicolons), change your type to `lang="sass"` and it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happened to come across an article:
https://daveceddia.com/svelte-with-sass-in-vscode/

This article showed the component style-tag with **type** instead of **lang**.

By changing the lang="scss" to type="text/scss" the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this post having seen the same error in a Vue project, but my issue was that I simply hadn't read the code properly: there was a block written by another dev that specified `<style lang='sass'>` and within that block I found a semicolon. Removing the semi colon (as you'd expect from the error message) fixed the problem. Equally, I could have changed the `lang` to `scss` and re-written that block in SCSS style.

I hope that's of assistance to someone else who looks here before they read the code!